# To know which UILongPressGestureRecognizer is triggered

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I add `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to several `UIButton` with the code :

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(btnLong:)];
[btnOne addGestureRecognizer:longPress]; //there are btnTwo, btnThree for example
```

And when I long press on a button the method is called:

```
-(void)btnLong:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{

    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    }
}
```

My question is, how can I know which `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` is triggered, because there is no tag property for `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give each button a unique tag number. Then in your action method you can do:

```
-(void)btnLong:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        UIView *view = gestureRecognizer.view;
        if (view.tag == 1) { // first button's tag
            // process 1st button
        } else if (view.tag == 2) { // second button's tag
            // process 2nd button
        }
    }
}
```

Another option, if you have outlets for each button you can do:

```
-(void)btnLong:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        UIView *view = gestureRecognizer.view;
        if (view == self.firstButton) {
            // process 1st button
        } else if (view == self.secondButton) {
            // process 2nd button
        }
    }
}
```

where `firstButton` and `secondButton` are your button properties. And yes, using `==` is appropriate for checking to see if the gesture's view is one of the buttons because you do mean to compare the object pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Why not put the gesture rec on the common `superview`?  Then you can determine which `UIView` was long-pressed by using `locationInView`, then accessing the view's tag property.

Comment: do you feel that it is boring to figure out the location of the super view to decide which one is cilicked

Answer (score 0):

I have used UIView as subview to tableview cell. And I applied UILongGesture to that. this is the code worked for me.

```
func handleLongPressGesture(_ longPressGestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer){

            if longPressGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began
            {
                let touchPoint = longPressGestureRecognizer.location(in: tableViewObj)

                            if let indexPath = tableViewObj.indexPathForRow(at: touchPoint)
                            {
                                print(indexPath.row)



                }
            }
}
```

You have index path. You can do whatever you need to do.